# getting string from database psql

Tags: node.js, database, string, psql

Hi I need help figuring out how to get my string entry in my database into a variable. All of my code works and if I copy and paste the exact string from my database into my bcrypt compare call it works perfectly. Basically my problem is that my variable "compare" prints out as

[{"password": "$2a$10$eilJb6SGKSSQm2b.U5tj.ut4o8.oHyJNVhbkpjcpeomCj4GlMEyqC"}]

but I just need

"$2a$10$eilJb6SGKSSQm2b.U5tj.ut4o8.oHyJNVhbkpjcpeomCj4GlMEyqC". Any ideas?

```
 account.on("end", function(result) {
    if(result.rows.length > 0){
        console.log("found account: ");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "   "));
        //turn the db entry into a string
        compare = JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "   ");
        //compare the hashed password from database to parameter for password change
        bcrypt.compare(password, compare, function(err, res) {
        console.log("res result: " + res);
            if(res){
                    console.log("passwords are same");
                    //new query updating the password in the db
                    if(person=="s"){
                        //update db
                        client.query('UPDATE students SET password=($2) WHERE email=($1)',
                        [req.body.email, hash_new]);
                        console.log("changed students password");
                    } else {
                        //update db
                        client.query('UPDATE teachers SET password=($2) WHERE email=($1)',
                        [req.body.email, hash_new]);
                        console.log("changed teacher password");
                    }
            } else {
            console.log("passwords are not the same");
            }
        });
    } else {
    console.log("account not found!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
compare = JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "   ");
```

try

```
compare = result.rows[0].password;
```

You don't need the JSON string but the JavaScript value.